# Draw Rectangle in ListViewItem but bigger than ListViewItem (overflow)?

Tags: xaml, uwp

In my UWP App I have ListView and need to draw Rectangles that fill one or 
several ListViewItems.
Logically, ListView is a list of calendar days, Rectangle is a event (that can be longer than one day). So the behavior like in default windows calendar - to show events on calendar.

This is simplified example - ListView with ListViewItem fixed height "60", and Rectangle in item DataTemplate with fixed height "120":

```
<ListView BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Days, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="60"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="260"/>                    
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Aqua"/>                    
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Appointments}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Blue"
                                        Stretch="Fill"
                                        Width="230"                                            
                                        Height="120" Tapped="Rectangle_Tapped"                                             
                                       >
                            </Rectangle>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

As result I saw rectangle with height "60" instead of "120":
[ScreenShot of result view](http://i.piccy.info/i9/f3d901c45734b2d65f6693f455df39ad/1446134010/2706/915686/3.png)

Can I do something for drawing Rectangle that can overflow several ListViewItems?

This is what I want to get:
[What I want to get](http://i.piccy.info/i9/f3d901c45734b2d65f6693f455df39ad/1446134010/2706/915686/3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the setter of "Height" in the ItemContainerStyle, then just define "Height" in the DataTemplate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but in this way I got bin first ListViewItem with Rectangle, and other ListViewItems are empty and small.
You can see result current here:

[Current](http://i.piccy.info/i9/a2eb4428671f729b4a05c6af06ce76ec/1446134006/3568/915686/2.png).

But I need result like this:
[Need to be](http://i.piccy.info/i9/f3d901c45734b2d65f6693f455df39ad/1446134010/2706/915686/3.png).

Comment: If you want the list items have unified height, then it is necessary to define it in the ItemContainerStyle. If your list item is sometimes too big to show, why not try  to add scrollview in your item template?

Comment: Thank you,

But I need to show for example that event duration will be 2 days (rectangle fill 2 listviewitems), like it is in windows calendar.

Seems I need to draw rectangles in a layer over ListItem, but I can't understand how.